# Mutable observable object in RxSwift or Combine

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, combine

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a mutable Array in viewModel that can also be observed by Controller and reload tableView when its value changes.
I tried to use `BehaviorRelay` but looks like it's immutable. I can't delete and insert data inside it's value.
The best thing I managed to write is this custom ObservableObject class:

```
final class CustomObservableObject<T> {

var value: T {
    didSet {
        listener?(value)
    }
}

init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
}

var listener: ((T) -> Void)?

func bind(listener: @escaping ((T) -> Void)) {
    self.listener = listener
}
```

}

which works exactly how I want. Is there anything I can use in the Combine or RxSwift framework like this class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BehaviorRelay is built for the specific purpose of storing state and allowing you to imperatively update it which is what you are asking for.

The BehaviorRelay type is a wrapper around the BehaviorSubject type and provides a different interface, one that does not allow the internal subject to emit an error or completed event. The Element contained in the BehaviorSubject *is* mutable. However, in order to mutate it you must first extract it into a `var` with `value` and then push the updated value back in with `accept(_:)`. This will help ensure that no mutations are missed and allows you to batch up multiple mutations into a single update. These are things missing in the class you wrote.

Please always remember though:

> Subjects [and Relays] provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use.
> -- [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com)

As you learn more about, and grow more comfortable with, the reactive paradigm you will find yourself reaching for this particular crutch less often.